# How to split a CSV file into multiple files based on second column value with header(not using AWK)

Tags: csv, batch-file

I need to be able to run a .bat file to look at this CSV and split off into multiple CSVs based on the value in Col C - Customer Code and each file generate with header in the file.

Eg.

```
 Invoice,PORef,CustomerCode,CustomerName,DocumentDate,ProductCode,ProductName
 111222,PO123,C100000,Test Store,1/1/15,AB1000,Test Soft Toy
 111222,PO123,C100000,Test Store,1/1/15,AB1002,Test Soft Toy2
 111222,PO321,C111000,My Store,1/10/15,AB1000,Test Soft Toy
 111222,PO123,C100000,Test Store,1/1/15,AB1001,Test Soft Toy1     
 111222,PO321,C111000,My Store,1/10/15,AB1001,Test Soft Toy1
 111222,PO321,C111000,My Store,1/10/15,AB1002,Test Soft Toy2
```

The .bat should run and split the CSV into 2 separate CSV's:

CSV1:

```
 Invoice,PORef,CustomerCode,CustomerName,DocumentDate,ProductCode,ProductName
 111222,PO123,C100000,Test Store,1/1/15,AB1000,Test Soft Toy
 111222,PO123,C100000,Test Store,1/1/15,AB1001,Test Soft Toy1
 111222,PO123,C100000,Test Store,1/1/15,AB1002,Test Soft Toy2
```

CSV2:

```
 Invoice,PORef,CustomerCode,CustomerName,DocumentDate,ProductCode,ProductName
 111222,PO321,C111000,My Store,1/10/15,AB1000,Test Soft Toy
 111222,PO321,C111000,My Store,1/10/15,AB1001,Test Soft Toy1
 111222,PO321,C111000,My Store,1/10/15,AB1002,Test Soft Toy2
```

Below is the code that I had try and search from internet but I still facing the problem to print the header for the output file and i not understand how to check the value at the column C

```
 @echo off
 set file=invoice.csv

 REM get header:
 set /p header=<%header%\invoice.csv

 REM process file line by line (ignore header):
 for /f "skip=1 tokens=,* delims=," %%a in (%file%) do (
  set line=%%1
   if not exist "%%a.csv" echo %header%>"%%a.csv"
   echo %%a,%%b>>"%%a.csv"
 )
```

Thank you for your helping^^

Comment: your question is `How to.... [not using AWK]` but you tagged it with `awk` tag... what do you mean? "hey, awk people, attention, look at here, pls don't use awk to solve this problem"

Comment: accept my condolences, because it can be done with one line of code using Unix awk command(powerful Unix Awk!)

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
set file=invoice.csv

REM get header:
set /p header=<%file%

REM process file line by line (ignore header):
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%A in (%file%) do (
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%B in ("%%A") do (
    if not exist "%%B.csv" echo %header%>"%%B.csv"
    >>"%%B.csv" echo %%A
  )
)
```

Comment: Sorry for disturb again...how should i continue if i need to analyze the multiple data  files using an awk file?The code that i had try is as follow:

@echo off
set file=invoice.csv

REM get header:
set /p header=<%file%

REM process file line by line (ignore header):
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%A in (%file%) do (
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%B in ("%%A") do (
    if not exist "%%B.csv" echo %header%>"%%B.csv"
    >>"%%B.csv" echo %%A
  )
 nawk -f "1.awk" %%B.csv >> 1.csv
)
But the result i get was wrong because it cannot read the B.csv file

Comment: Please don't post a whole batch in a comment - it's difficult to read without line breaks. If my answer satisfies your question you should honor that by voting up or check mark as answer. To get a broader audience you should ask new questions as such and with then proper tags.

Comment: Bit of a long shot, but how do I compensate for fields that do include a comma?

Answer (score 0):

Given that none of the fields (or cell values) in the CSV data contain commas `,` on its own (which is valid in CSV when the value is enclosed in `""`), you can use a single [`findstr` command](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) line to filter for the needed information, even including the header row. To write the extracted data to a file, use [output redirection `>`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html). Here is some example code:

```cmd
findstr /I /R %= use regular epression search; remove `/I` for case-sensitive search =% ^
    /C:"^[^,]*,[^,]*,CustomerCode," %= third column header; omit to skip header =% ^
    /C:"^[^,]*,[^,]*,C100000,"      %= third column value; there may be more =% ^
    "invoice.csv" > "invoice_C100000.csv"
findstr /I /R %= use regular epression search; remove `/I` for case-sensitive search =% ^
    /C:"^[^,]*,[^,]*,CustomerCode," %= third column header; omit to skip header =% ^
    /C:"^[^,]*,[^,]*,C111000,"      %= third column value; there may be more =% ^
    "invoice.csv" > "invoice_C111000.csv"
```

Or written in one line each without any in-line comments:

```cmd
findstr /I /R /C:"^[^,]*,[^,]*,CustomerCode," /C:"^[^,]*,[^,]*,C100000," "invoice.csv" > "invoice_C100000.csv"
findstr /I /R /C:"^[^,]*,[^,]*,CustomerCode," /C:"^[^,]*,[^,]*,C111000," "invoice.csv" > "invoice_C111000.csv"
```

The used search strings (or regular expressions) like `^[^,]*,[^,]*,CustomerCode,` mean:

- `^` -- anchor matches to the beginning of lines;
- twice the same sequence:

  - `[^,]` -- defines an inverse character class and matches any character except the `,`;
  - `*` -- matches the preceding expression zero or more times;
  - `,` -- matches a literal comma `,`;
- `CustomerCode` -- literal part of the search string matching the column header (or the column values `C100000` or `C111000`);
- `,` -- matches a literal comma;
- the remaining line string is not regarded;